# Scut work and scab worker

Tags: etymology

I wonder if the term scut work, used in american hospitals, could be related to the term scab worker, as in a lowly person who crosses picket lines, since it relates to work that doctors will, and will not, do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning and etymology of 'scut' from 'scut work'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35934/what-is-the-meaning-and-etymology-of-scut-from-scut-work).`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misapprehsension that could be cured by consulting a dictionary.

Comment: After reviewing the rules, I can see how my question was really about American labor history, and therefor off topic, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J.S. Farmer & W.E. Henley, *Slang & Its Analogues* (1903) has entries for *scab* and *scut* (and *scute*) but doesn't associate any of those words with nonunion, strike-breaking workers. Here are the entries:

> SCAB, subs. (old).—1. A rascal " spec[ifically] a constable or  sheriff's officer: often jocular. Hence SCABBY (or SCAB)=contemptible; beggarly; SCABBY-SHEEP = a ne'er-do-weel; SCABILONIAN [cross reference omitted] [First citation is from 1591 (Lyly).]

and

> SCUT, *subs.* (venery).—1. The female pudendum [cross reference omitted] and (2) the pubic hair [cross reference omitted] [First citation is from 1596 (Shakespeare).]
>
> SCUTE. *subs.* (old).—(1) A small coin: hence a low standard. [First citation is from 1596 (Nash).]

Eric Partidge, *A Dictionary of Slang an Unconventional English*, first edition (1936) reports the same original meaning of *scab* as Farmer & Henley, but then adds this second definition:

> **scab.** ... 2.—Hence, a workman refusing to strike, esp. one working while his companions are on strike: orig. (1811), U.S., anglicised ca. 1880. Occ[asionally] attrbutively.

Partridge does not have an entry for *scut*. Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner *Dictionary of American Slang*, first edition (1960), covers both words, however:

> **scab** *n*. A worker who refuses to join a union or go on strike; esp. , a worker who will cross a union picket line to take  the place of a striking worker.

and

> **scut** *n.* **1** A contemptible or mean person --> **2** An inexperienced person; a newcomer, rookie, apprentice, or fraternity pledge. **3 = scud** ["Hard boring, or tedious tasks; minor details that are unrewarding and time-consuming."]

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995), pushes the origin of scab in the sense of attempted strikebreaker to "by 1777." It also has this lengthy entry for *scut*:

> **scut 1 *n*** *by 1873* A detestable or contemptible person; =CRUMB, LOUSE [citation omitted] **2 *n*** *by 1950s* A novice; recruit; neophyte [citation omitted] **3 *n*** (also **scud** or **scut work**) *by 1950s* Menial work such as would be given to a novice [citation omitted] **4 *n*** (also **scut dog** or **scut monkey** or **scut puppy**) *medical by 1940s* A junior intern or physician **5 *n*** (also **scut work**) *medical by 1940s* Routine and tedious medical procedures usually relegated to the least senior member of the staff {the 1500s slang use, "vulva, cunt" and the standard use "tail of a hare or deer," suggest a core sense "tail, buttocks, ass," reinforced by British dialect *skut*, "crouch down," and perhaps related to Old Norse *skutr*, "stern of a ship"; *scut* meant "little boy," perhaps fr Scots *scudler*, "scullion, kitchen boy," among Scotch-Irish settlersin Pennsylvania}

So even though at one stage or another in their evolution both *scab* and *scut* were used to refer to "a contemptible person," there is no evidence that one term gave rise to the other. Both terms have long histories that help explain their current meanings without reference to one another.